# Why does the Num typeclass have an abs method?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I’m thinking about standard libraries (or preludes) for functional languages.

If I have `Ord` instance for `n`, then it is trivial to implement `abs`:

```
abs n = if n > 0 then n else (-n)
```

In the case of vector spaces, the absolute value (length) of a vector is very important. But the type doesn’t match because the absolute value of a vector is not a vector: it is a real number.

What was the design rationale behind having `abs` (or `signum`) as part of the `Num` typeclass?

Comment: "If I have Ord instance for n, then it is trivial to implement abs: abs n = if n > 0 then n else (-n)" and where are you going to get `-` and `0` from?

Comment: @newacct: I'm pretty sure the OP means "If I have Num _and_ Ord...".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vectors are not good `Num` candidates. There's [a dedicated class for those](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.6/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html).

But `Num` has many useful instances for which there is no `Ord`. Basically, `(Num, Ord) ≈ Real` in Haskell, which hints quite clearly that the obvious non-Ord types are the higher [division algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra), foremostly `Complex`. Here, `abs` is again not quite perfect because it could return a real number, but as these are a subset of the complex plane returning `Complex` is not *wrong*.

Other examples are more abstract types, e.g.

```
instance (Num n) => Num (a->n) where
  f+g = \x -> f x + g x
  ...
  abs f = abs . f
```

which is not `Ord` simply because you can't fully evaluate a function, only its return values. (This also prevents an `Eq` instance, so this is not legal in Haskell98 where `Eq` is a superclass of `Num`).

To adress the question in the title: it is a bit disputed whether it was a good idea to put `abs` in `Num`. The [numeric prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) has it as [a complete seperate class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/numeric-prelude/0.4.0.3/doc/html/Algebra-Absolute.html), which allows you to make e.g. also vectors an instance of the other num-classes, but not of `Absolute.C`. The downside is that this results in a much more complicated class hierarchy, which often just isn't worth the effort.